# Issue with pushing big image to harbor repository

Tags: docker, harbor

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to push a large image (~1 GB) to an internally hosted Harbor repository. Upon completion of pushing the largest layer, I receive the following error:

```
7ba86e9d77ed: Pushed
ca342045cd28: Pushed
5f70bf18a086: Layer already exists                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           fa207eefdbc6: Pushed
0d3699b83b74: Pushing [==================================================>]  740.4MB
b60202ed5161: Pushed
9215743a08fe: Pushed
c2497f867b97: Pushed
c0fcee1f0005: Pushed
e29c10a8f5af: Pushed
5c4895a3935f: Pushed
df651bb07449: Pushed
7d578c5b3942: Pushed
498bbcc60d01: Layer already exists
c0e21dcee623: Layer already exists
d6b19a46b795: Layer already exists
e6c05e83c163: Layer already exists
256d88da4185: Layer already exists
unauthorized: unauthorized to access repository: nvidia-operator/driver, action: push: unauthorized to access repository: nvidia-operator/driver, action: push
```

However, using the same credentials, I'm able to push smaller images (I've tested with busybox by simply pulling and retagging it) without any problem.

Anyone had similar issues?

Comment: Historically, I've had trouble pushing individual layers above about 1 GB.  If possible, breaking up the layer into smaller parts will help, but this does depend on what specifically is in the Dockerfile.

Comment: depending on the version of Harbor, this used to be a problem. To my knowledge, since 2.7 or earlier it should be no issue. I think the problem has to do with the config, setup, nlb, or s3.